# caffe installation doesn't find python 3.5 even if it is installed and labeled in path variables

Tags: python, deep-learning, python-3.5, caffe

I have installed python 3.5 and when I type `python` into **cmd** it says

> Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

But when I try to download [caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) by running `build_win.cmd` it keeps giving me this error. I'm completely lost on how to debug this. Any ideas??

> Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.16299.
>   -- Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required is at least "2.7" (found C:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe)
>   CMake Error at cmake/WindowsDownloadPrebuiltDependencies.cmake:40 (message):
>     Could not find url for MSVC version = 1900 and Python version = 1.4.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:77 (include)

Also, I have no idea why it says **"(found C:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe)"** because that file doesn't exist. I deleted that entire `Python36` folder. So how is that statement showing?

I tried:

1. Restarting **cmd**
2. Restarting computer
3. Re-downloading python altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caffe stores its own cache and in it, it keeps file locations saved. So, even if a particular location file was deleted, the cache will tell the installer that it's still there. Go to `caffe/scripts/build` and delete the entire `CMakeFiles` folder. This will reset everything and the next time you try to install caffe, it will find the current Python folder.